# How can I use iOS-Charts create a LineChartView With have multiple labelTextColor YAxis

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts, yaxis

I need to make a stock app recently that has a LineChartView with multiple labelTextColor in YAxis. like this image [image: Stock gains].

I didn't find any same question.

Answer (score 0):

[Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/) library includes a [demo app](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo-iOS) inside it.

Have look and choose what fits for you.

you can also check out [awesome-ios-chart](https://github.com/ameizi/awesome-ios-chart) link